# Match multiple strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to see whether or not 2 strings match.

```
example: 1234.5678.9012.3456 => 5678.1234.3456 = match
```

This matches because the second string of number are also in the first one. I did this with the following code:

```
<?php
$haystack =  '1234.5678.9012.3456';
$needle = '5678.1234.3456';
$regex = '/(?=.*'. str_replace(".",")(?=.*",$needle) .').*$/'; 
    // regex looks like this /(?=.*5678)(?=.*1234)(?=.*3456).*$/

if(preg_match($regex, $haystack)){
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Here is my problem, when there are duplicate numbers.

```
example: 1234.5678.9012.3456 => 5678.5678.3456 = dont match 
         1234.5678.5678.3456 => 5678.5678.3456 = match
```

The first example doesnt match because 5678 occurs twice but the first string only has 5678 once. In the second example 5678 occurs twice as well and therefor matches the second string.

My question: How could I change my regex,

Comment: Isn't `strpos` enough here?

Comment: Instead of using regular expressions, use `split()` to split each string into an array of strings, and then use `array_diff()` to check if everything in the second is in the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You choose a very complicated way to do that. You can check what you want in a more simple way using `array_diff`:

```
var_dump(array_diff(explode('.', $needle), explode('.', $haystack)));
```

when the resulting array is empty the condition is true.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$haystack =  '1234.5678.9012.3456';
$needle = '5678.5678.3456';

$needle_array = explode(".", $needle);
//print_r($needle_array);

$haystack_array = explode(".", $haystack);
//print_r($haystack_array);

$intersect = array_intersect($needle_array, $haystack_array);
//print_r($intersect);

if(count($intersect) > 0){
    echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "Doesn't match";
}
?>
```

Comment: The fact the intersection isn't empty doesn't prove that all elements of the needle array are in this intersection. However, instead of counting the number of elements in the intersection, you can compare the intersection with the needle array.

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte. He wants this: 1234.5678.9012.3456 => 5678.5678.3456 to return a match.